# How Can I improve this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to improve the performance of this query as it is taking 3-4 seconds to execute.
Here is the query

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
ac.account_id,
ac.account_name,
cl.name AS client_name,
IFNULL(cn.contact_number, "") AS Phone
FROM accounts AS ac
STRAIGHT_JOIN clients AS cl ON cl.client_id = ac.client_id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT bc.contact_number, bc.account_id
  FROM contact_numbers AS bc
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT account_id, MAX(number_id) AS number_id
    FROM contact_numbers
    WHERE status = 1 AND contact_type != "Fax" AND contact_link = "Account"
    GROUP BY account_id
  ) AS bb ON bb.number_id = bc.number_id
) AS cn ON ac.account_id = cn.account_id

WHERE ac.status = 1
ORDER BY ac.account_name
LIMIT 0, 100
```

the client table contains about 10 rows that's why I have straight join. The account table contains 350K records. The contact_numbers contains about 500k records
I believe the problem here is the left Join and also the ORDER BY but I am not sure how to work around it. Also I am using SQL_NO_CACHE because the accounts, contact_numbers tables are being updated at a fast rate.

What else can I do to improve performance of this query?

this is a screenshot of the explain on this query

[image]

I am using MySQL 5.6.13 
I Set sort_buffer_size=1M
My server has 32GB of RAM

Comment: 3-4 seconds isn't bad.  Now if it was 3-4 minutes then I would be trying to improve it.

Comment: It is a query that is constantly being used! So I am trying to help it as much as possible. Plus I am expecting my records to increase dramatically very soon. 4 seconds now will take 10 seconds once the data increased

Comment: The problem of the query is that you deal with results of nested subqueries. The results are large and have no (and can not have) any indexes.

Comment: @newtover So do you have a suggestion to solve the problem?

Comment: This should help you:
[MySQL - Join tables, retrieve only Max ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775561/mysql-join-tables-retrieve-only-max-id)

Answer (score 0):

- The below should make the outer query run without requiring a filesort.

  ```
  CREATE INDEX ac_status_acctname ON accounts (status, account_name);
  ```
- The below should make the inner query `Using index`, and help it to do the GROUP by without using a temp table.

  ```
  CREATE INDEX cn_max ON contact_numbers (account_id, status, contact_link, 
    contact_type, number_id);
  ```
- You need to join on both account_id and number_id to get the greatest entry per account. The way you have it now, you just get *any* account that happens to have the same number_id, which is probably not what you intended, and it could be what's generating too many rows for the subquery result set.

  ```
   bc INNER JOIN ... bb ON bb.account_id = bc.account_id AND bb.number_id = bc.number_id
  ```

  You can also write the same join condition as:

  ```
   bc INNER JOIN ... bb USING (account_id, number_id)
  ```

Comment: Thanks Bill, the value number_id is the primary AUTO_INCREMENTAL value and. what I am trying to do here is since an account_id can have many phone numbers I am trying to identify only 1 non-fax number that's why I am using the sub-queries. I am not sure if I understand your solution correctly. as for the first create index. I am not sure if it will help as the query is dynamic sometimes an extra filter is added "ac.client_id = 4" and also some times I add a filter AND account_name LIKE "a%";

Comment: Right; you'll need different indexes for each of those differences in query. I only answer for the query you showed.

Comment: I see, but what about  bc INNER JOIN ... bb ON bb.account_id = bc.account_id AND bb.number_id = bc.number_id? why would I want to include the account_id?

Comment: Bill, adding the index (status, account_name) did not help. I also tried to force the use of it which increased the time for some reason.

Comment: Not knowing your current table definitions or how many rows, etc. I can't make any more recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

I would actualy rewrite the query. You currently select a lot of data you do not need and discard. I would minimize the amount of the fetched data.

It seems you basically select something for each account with a certain status and take only 100 of them. So I would put this in a subquery:

```
SELECT 
  account_id,
  account_name,
  c.name AS client_name,
  IFNULL(contact_number, '') as Phone
FROM (
  SELECT 
    account_id,
    MAX(number_id) as number_id
  FROM (
    SELECT account_id
    FROM accounts
    WHERE status = 1 -- other conditions on accounts go here
    ORDER BY account_name
    LIMIT 0, 100) as a
  LEFT JOIN contact_numbers n
    ON a.coount_id = n.account_id 
      AND n.status = 1 
      AND contact_type != "Fax" 
      AND contact_link = "Account"
  GROUP BY account_id) an
LEFT JOIN contact_numbers USING (account_id, number_id)
JOIN accounts a USING (account_id)
JOIN clients c USING (client_id);
```

You will need `(status, account_name)` index for `accounts` table (for the query with client_id = 4 `(status, client_id, account_name)` as well) and an index on `account_id` in contact_numbers. This should suffice.